# php variable on separate page not working

Tags: php, variables, foreach, global

Can anyone help on this please. It's driving me crazy!

I have on one page:

```
foreach($images_not_on_server_unique as $img => $missing){
    foreach($test as $m => $n){
        foreach($n as $o => $p){
            $query1 = "SELECT * FROM $p WHERE adv='$missing'";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query1) or die(mysqli_error());
            $numofrows = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
            if($numofrows >= '1'){
                $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
                $errors_images++;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo $errors_images;
```

which correctly prints out '16'.

On another page I include the page, and then echo the variable from the first page like so:

```
echo "errors images ".$errors_images;
```

which should give me '16'. However, I get only 'errors images'.

What am I doing wrong. I have used include many, many times before and it has always worked (but maybe not in a foreach loop). I have tried using $GLOBALS, but to no avail.

Many thanks for any help.

*EDIT*

The full code for the second page

```
<?php 
include("login/include/session.php"); 
include("dbconnect/index_new.php"); 
require("errors/q_errors.php"); 
include_once("errors/q_missing_images.php"); 
echo "errors images ".$errors_images; 
?>
```

UPDATE:

I have added

```
$my_test = '555';
```

to the first page and echoed it in the second page with

```
echo "my test ". $my_test;
```

and it works correctly!
Therefore it must have something to do with the foreach function in the first page.

Comment: Do you mean you only see the string `errors images` with no number?

Comment: Did you use include(filename) or require(filename)?

Comment: Please provide more code. Did you include file? don't you override variable from the included file?

Comment: What creates this variable `$images_not_on_server_unique`

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: RiggsFolly: the code is very long. I have included the error checking you suggested and it throws no errors, but the variable now does not print to screen. CORRECTION: it DOES print the variable to screen.

Comment: It is a good codestyle to define your variable before using in a loop, like `$errors_images = 0;`

Comment: The problem also can be that you are running that cycle inside a function. in this case variable wouldn't be visible outside of that function unless you make it visible using `global $abc;` syntax

Answer (score 0):

Either you're including the file incorrectly

```
include_once 'path/to/file.php';
```

Or you're calling it incorrectly

```
echo 'errors images'.$errors_images.'';
```

Comment: The first page is called 'q_missing_images.php' and is included in the second page with 'require("errors/q_missing_images.php");'

Comment: _Small Point_ The trailing `.''` is totally redundant

Comment: I have tried with 'include', 'include_once' and 'require'. I do have another include on the second page and that works correctly!

Comment: George, you are going to have to show us the real code, or at least a better fuller example of the code you have in the second page

Comment: The code in the second page:

<?php
include("login/include/session.php");
include("dbconnect/index_new.php");
require("errors/q_errors.php");
include_once("errors/q_missing_images.php");

echo "errors images ".$errors_images;
?>

Comment: **NO** Please add all extra info to you r question, using the edit link. Nobody can read code in a comment